# No me introduce los datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Apliqué el siguiente codigo y no logro que los datos se metan en la base de datos. Lo conexion está hecha con PDO y sí funciona. Lo mas raro es que si hardcodeo los diferentes campos ahí sí los introduce.

```
if (empty($errores)) {
   $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
   $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
   $carrera = $_POST["carrera"];
   $año = $_POST["año"];
   $comision = $_POST["comision"];
   $fDN = $_POST["date"];
   $dni = $_POST["DNI"];
   $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];

   $consulta = $baseDeDatos->prepare("INSERT into alumnos values (:apellido, :nombre, :DNI, :fnac,
:telefono, :email, :carrera, :año, :comision)");

   $consulta->bindValue(":apellido", $apellido);
   $consulta->bindValue(":nombre", $nombre);
   $consulta->bindValue(":DNI", $dni);
   $consulta->bindValue(":fnac", $fDN);
   $consulta->bindValue(":telefono", $telefono);
   $consulta->bindValue(":email", $email);
   $consulta->bindValue(":carrera", $carrera);
   $consulta->bindValue(":año", $año);
   $consulta->bindValue(":comision", $comision);

   $consulta->execute();
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba poniendo los `values` en el mismo orden en que estan declarados los campos en  la tabla. Si no especificas los campos; se toman en el orden que estan en tu tabla, que por lo regular es el orden que fueron creados.

Comment: hola! estan en el mismo orden que en la tabla y si aclaro los campos que quiero rellenar tanto lo hace.

Comment: Intenta de esta forma cambiando `bindValue` por `bindParam`, algo asi: `$consulta->bindParam(':comision', $comision);` y asi con todos. Saludos.

Comment: tampoco funciona

Comment: ¿És la consulta preparada antes de ejecutarla?

Comment: la conexion funciona porque me ya he probado traer datos de otra tabla y lo hace, además si harcodeo los datos sin bindearlos ahí sí los introduce

Comment: listo, ya está resuelto. Habia un problema con los tipos de datos. Muchas gracias!